# ParentWindow in a DLL

Tags: delphi, dll

I'm trying to assign a ParentWindow, to a control created in a dll. The control is an editor, I need to process a text file, but this control requires a ParentWindow.

How can I solve this problem, if I create this control in a dll?

I'm using Delphi 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also create the TForm (maybe not Visible) inside the dll then the control and add it to the form

Comment: it's a good answer, but i resolved sending as argument my form handle into the dll

Comment: Then why not provide your solution as an answer and by that possibly help others having similar problems? You could even accept your own anser after a day.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question, and the correct answer is "Don't do that".

The first question I have is "why do you feel the need to create a control in a DLL?"  Why not just create it in code or include the control itself in your EXE?

Second, if you want to add a control to a separate binary, but it in a Package.   Packages are designed specifically to make exporting controls simple and easy.

Comment: Personally I think that's a bit of a silly answer.  What if I wanted to use something like a scintilla type of control.  I can't embed it in the .exe as it's an external .dll.  I could include it as .obj files but that's assuming you have the original src.  How about the Mozilla embeddable controls.  Why can't I parent something created in a third-party DLL to a Delphi form?  Packages are not the end all-be all of exporting controls.  I've used packages in the past and wont use them now unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Well, downvoting it seems a bit much, given that it is technically accurate, and most of the time, putting a Delphi control into a DLL is the /wrong/ thing to do.

Comment: I'm very interested in reading up on the topic of splitting a Delphi application into one main shell application and a number of separate extension packages.  Can you suggest a good summary of this subject I could read?

Comment: Larry --

I'd start here:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=delphi+plugin+framework&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_enUS333US334&ie=UTF-8&aq=0&oq=delphi+plugin

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the parent window from somewhere! Typically the host application that loads and calls the DLL would supply a window handle. It looks like your DLL provides a custom control for an application, so of course the application needs to supply a parent window handle.

Also, you typically need a window handle to the entire application as well, which you set as Application.Handle before you do anything else in your DLL.

Answer (score 0):

ok, thaks for your answers, i already solved (a few minutes before first answer).

first, i need explain why i don't embed, and that is because costumer ask me that way.

the solution is send my form handle to my dll as an argument, after testing that way, i got no errors...

only modificate the prototype of my procedure, to recieve a HWND as an argument, to ParentWindow prop of my control (created in memory).
that's all.

Comment: Nick, your answer is correct, personally i won't do that again if i'm doing a "standalone" app, but you know, costumers change requeriments all the time.

Ryan, your point it's correct too, next time i'll ask requeriments first.

Smasher, this is the solution, i don't think 'bout others with similar problems.

thanks to all.